# Is there any way to move apps to my SD with Android 2.1?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, app2sd

Is there any possible way to move apps to my SD card on my Droid Eris?  I keep getting that low memory icon in my notification bar and its really annoying.  I'm running Android 2.1

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/how-to-install-apk-files-on-sdcard

Comment: I have a Motorola Cliq, and same thing, low memory!  Not sure how Froyo plays into the question though, it was more of a HOW do you make it do it ... so that would mean tell us how to root and install Apps2SD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a built-in feature of Froyo, as long as the developer has built the app that way.

However, you're mostly out of luck, unless you're willing to root your phone and install Cyanogenmod and [APPS2SD](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Apps2SD) or jump through the hoops Bruce details in [his answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/is-there-anyway-to-move-apps-to-my-sd-with-android-2-1/6794#6794).

If you do have Android 2.2 or higher, the app [SDMove](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.beaglebros.SDMove) can be a big help in moving apps in bulk. [SDWatch](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.beaglebros.SDWatch) is also useful, as it monitors apps you install and alerts you if it can be moved the SD card. (There are, of course, other apps that do the same things. They're just the ones I've used.)

Comment: I can't find apps2sd on the market, is it part of the android sdk? or should I be looking somewhere else? Also, the market links to those sd apps is greyed out for my 2.1 phone.

Comment: I doubt APPS2SD will be on the Market, because it requires root. Also, the OS support for moving apps to the SD card came in 2.2, so obviously apps that use that functionality will not be available for for previous versions.

Comment: so, in short, there's no way to move apps to SD in 2.1 then? :-(

Comment: also FWIW, there are apps in the market that require root, the drocap2 screenshot app for example.

Comment: @travis: Not without rooting the phone.

Comment: @Al, I'm confused :-) So there is a way to do it with a phone that is rooted, but doesn't have a custom ROM? Can you point me somewhere that explains how? The only directions I've seen have installing Cyanogen as the first step. Thanks.

Comment: @travis: No, cyanogenmod would appear to be a pre-requisite. http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Apps2SD

Comment: I've updated my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Actually, turns out there is a way for 2.1, no cyanogenmod required. =)

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is way. It's not perfectly seamless, and it requires that you partition your SD card yourself. The steps below were provided by [Sparx](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/1250/sparx) as an [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/sd-card-partitioning-why-how/6438#6438) to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6435/1926).

It worked for me, and I'm running stock android 2.1 on a Motorola milestone.

---

Enter [Link2SD](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) - it's freeware and works with Android 1.6 and above.

You will also need a partitioning tool - I used the excellent freeware [Easeus Partition Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) (EPM) to ensure no data was erased during the repartitioning / resizing.

1. First, download and install EPM.
2. Pop your storage card into your card reader.
3. Start EPM
4. Your card should be visible amongst the other drives/partitions in your PC.
5. Select the partition on your card - it should cover the entire length by default. Right-click & choose RESIZE/MOVE and then REDUCE the Partition Size (this is what shows in Windows) until the Unallocated Space size is of a suitable size. (The Unallocated space will be allocated as the partition on which your apps will be stored.) Click OK.

An aside - even though Link2SD supports the creation of the second partition (in which your apps will reside) in the FAT / FAT32 format, Windows only recognizes the first PRIMARY partition which is why this newly created partition won't show within Windows inspite of it being FAT / FAT32. We shall be using either ext2 / ext3 or ext4 as the file system in any case.

Onward...

6. Right-click this new Unallocated Space and choose CREATE. Click YES on the warning that describes what I've said above.
7. Now, in the Partition Label, type in a label like "AndroidApps" or whatever suits you.
8. This is CRITICAL - the CREATE AS should be PRIMARY
9. Choose File System as EXT3 and click OK.
10. Click APPLY in the main window's TOP LEFT corner (big blue check mark icon). EPM will carry out the operations. Congrats! You've just re-partitioned your card and without any data loss too. (Hopefully!)

Assuming you've installed Link2SD in your phone and the SD card has been re-inserted. 
11. Reboot your phone.

12. Start Link2SD and it should detect your partition.
13. A list of apps is now displayed. Click the app you want to move to the card and then click CREATE LINK.

That's it.

Comment: has this method worked for anyone with a metropcs Huawei with Android 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

There is [titanium backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). It's [description](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) says:

> You can move any app (or app data) to/from the SD card.
>
> Requires Android:
>       1.0 and up

It has a free version. It requires `root`: [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)