# Is there any way to move apps to my sd card in android 2.1 on my phone?

Tags: external-sd, 2.1-eclair, app2sd

Is there any way for me to move apps to my sd card in android 2.1 on my phone?  Everything I've read so far just talks about how easy it is to do it in 2.2.  I have a Milestone, but apparently my carrier is not yet able to support 2.2.   Am I just pretty much screwed until it does?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/how-to-install-apk-files-on-sdcard

Comment: @AlEverett This is not a duplicate. This question discusses ways to move apps to SD on Android 2.1 or lower. App2sd was introduced with Android 2.2

Comment: Then how about this nearly-identically-titled question? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/is-there-any-way-to-move-apps-to-my-sd-with-android-2-1

Answer (score 4):

You would have to root your phone and partition your SD card.  Note that the app itself must also support running from the SD card.  See [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=692367) for an example of how to do it for the Milestone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android 2.1 you can use [Link2SD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) app. 
To use this application your phone must be rooted and your SDCard should have ext2 [OR] ext3 partitions.

After successful installation of this application, it creates a Auto mount script and asks for reboot the phone.

**How to move already installed applications to SDCard ?**

Open the Link2SD application and Open the Menu. Select the Filter and Select **Not Linked User** filter. The menu gets closed and shows the list of applications that are installed by the User. Now select any application and Select **Create Link** option on the screen. It asks for confirmation. Once you say Ok then moves the application and related files into the SD Card.

**How to automatically move the Applications that are about to Install ?**

Open the Link2SD application and Open the Menu. Now select **Settings** and there is an option in Settings called **Auto Link**. Check that option. Thats it it moves the applications to SDCard as soon as they installed on Phone Memory.

**Tools to Partition the SDCard**

There are tools available to partition your SDCARD. On Windows Machine you can use **Minitool Partition** software and on linux you can use **gparted**.