# how to use ext partition in my android?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire, partitions, ext3

I partitioned my MicroSD card and created 1GB ext3 partition.

- What is the next step so I can use it to make the performance of my android better? It seems to me that it is mounted into /sd-ext
- What are all the options I can use ext for?

---

CM7 on HTC Desire

Comment: well it seems to me that it is not the best idea to use ext3 for swap. And we can store app on FAT so I will not user ext3 at all ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [discussed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6438/sd-card-partitioning-why-how), you can store apps on the ext3 partition which will free up internal phone memory. There are also apps like [Swapper2](https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.swapper2) which allow you to put your swap file on the SD Card.

Be warned, that this will degrade the life of your SD Card and will also chew up battery due to frequent read/writes to the card. Weigh the potential of additional free space in view of this.

Comment: I am after the second paragraph you wrote down. Could you elaborate more so I can choose better if I am going to use ext3 at all or not. So far it seems to me that it is not the best thing to do for me ...

Comment: Could you explain why you feel so? What part do you need clarification on?

Comment: I do not need much of clarification but more info why yes or no. Let's say I have never thought that swap will degrade the life time of SD card and that it will also chew up battery. So I am happy to hear any more info on that topic from somebody who knows ... more than me :-) that's it.

Comment: @Radek Using the SD card for swap will degrade it because the device will be writing to it all the time, just as it does with main memory.  SD cards are designed for storage (infrequent writes).  And as Sparx said, all the reads and writes take battery power.

Comment: @Matthew: I understood that never thought about that before so I was wondering if there are more 'points' like that to consider why YES or why NOT :-)