# Can I format SD to FAT32 from FAT16?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, external-sd, partitions

I saw that my SD card is FAT16 formatted. In order to improve performance, can I reformat it as FAT32? What filesystems does Android support for external storage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use FAT32 with no problems.  Android supports FAT/FAT16 and FAT32, and I believe raw / unformatted cards may work with some phones.  You can also use EXT partitions but this requires some extra work, see for example [how to use ext partition in my android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6764/how-to-use-ext-partition-in-my-android)

Comment: Nice, it will really improve my Android performance??? Will I see visible improvements this way?

Comment: @StickBumps Generally speaking, the advantages of FAT32 are that it allows you to have more files with longer filenames, and waste less space due to better cluster sizing.  (See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940351.aspx) for more info.) It shouldn't affect speed very much.

Comment: in order to get speed improvements, spend the extra money and buy the highest class rating card you can find. at least a class 6, or a class 10.

Comment: @Diogo There's an extreme class from SanDisk too. It's far more faster than class 10, but its slightly expensive.