# Link2sd: boot loop at reboot

Tags: link2sd, boot-loop

I'm happy with link2sd functionality (just installed: everything looks awesome, lots of free space). I reboot and my Acer liquid metal is stuck in bootloop.
I take the sd out, boot again and everything is ok. I pop the sd in while the phone is one and I can't see my apps on sd :(
Something is wrong with link2sd mount script but how can I debug this?

Comment: Could you explore /data/sdext2 folder? Is there any files and/or folders?

Comment: Can you read the contents of the card on your PC via a card reader? If so, I suggest you back up all the contents on the FAT partition, format the whole SD card, re-partition and try again. With Link2SD, ALWAYS unmount the card before ejecting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following 
[Issue with the Apps that are installed on SD Card after reinserting the SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9916/issue-with-the-apps-that-are-installed-on-sd-card-after-reinserting-the-sd-card)

I was one of the Hard user of Link2SD application. What I observed from this app is that you should not remove your SD card once you have applications on your SD Card. While phone booting some of the applications gets initialized.

If the phone system does not find the SD Card and its applications then it is going to break the link between the SD Card applications and the system. 

You might be seeing those applications on `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications` 
but they won't be accessible.

To answer your question there might be a way but not known to all. You can mail the developer of Link2SD mentioning the issue. They might give you a solution.