# Problem partitioning SD

Tags: external-sd, partitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SD card partitioning? why? how?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/sd-card-partitioning-why-how)

I am trying to partition my sd card on my Samsung Galaxy Ace because I want to extend my memory using the app link2sd but I have some problems doing it.

I am following this procedure which I first tried on my HTC Desire with perfect results:

```
open gparted
search for the filesystem I am interested in
make a first fat32 partition of 3GB for the SD
make a second ext3 partition of 800MB to extend internal memory and use link2sd    
apply
```

At this point I get an error, gparted is unable to do the first partition. If I try to change the orders/types of partition the error is always the same. Now I have a not allocated SD which is working to host data but I'd like it to work as an extension of my internal memory.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't provide the error message, so I can only take a good guess: As it already happened at the first partition: Did you first delete the (only) partition on the card? Otherwise: No free space left to create any (new) partition ;)

Comment: I am sorry you are right. This is a link to a folder where there is the file saved by gparted wuth the errors: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nea2gor32pwqjcl/nOXnzD67Fc Unfortunately it is formatted in html so not very very easy to read.

Comment: I think I first deleted the only partition on the sd card

Comment: Yes, you did -- as the "create partition" in your log stated "Success" (btw: Hard to read an HTML file in dropbox -- plain text would have been easier). The error occurs when creating the file system; looks like another process still accesses the partition ("Device or resource busy"). Would be helpful if you explain the steps you performed.

Comment: Yes sorry it's quite hard. How could I share the file? By the way, it is pretty difficult to remember the exact steps I performed because I got quite nervous and started to try all the possible combinations between orders and types of partitions. Probably I firstly deleted the existent partition and tried a start over, obviously without success. I can't understand the error though, if the SD card is empty, how can't a new partition work?

Comment: It's quite a while since I last used gparted. Maybe the [gparted FAQ and manual](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/help.php) offer some help?

Comment: I didn't find my specific problem there, unfortunately... is there any alternative software that will let me save my sd card (and phone using link2sd)?

Comment: On Linux, I normally use `cfdisk` and `mkfs` directly. But following the steps of the gparted manual precisely, you should also be able to partition and format your card? Maybe you try in two steps: Start gparted, create the partitions, write your changes, exit gparted. Start gparted again, format your partitions, done. [Step-by-Step in gparted manual](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-create-new-partition) should also do.

Comment: It's not working, I always get the error in the first step, when I create the main partition...