# What should I do now to move apps to SD in my Samsung Galaxy S Duos (ICS)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, app2sd, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I just bought a new Samsung Galaxy S Duos and the Android version does not have a option to move the app to memory card. I also installed the app called "app2sd"and when I open the app it says, `The device does not have a real primary external storage or the primary external storage is emulated. Moving app to SD function may not be supported by this device.`

What should I do now to move the app to SD.

Comment: Can you use a terminal on the device or ADB shell to run `echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and tell us what it says?  `ls -l /sdcard` and `ls /mnt` may also be helpful.

Comment: please, inform us: 1) your phone is rooted? 2) do you really have a external storage sd card?

Answer (score 1):

I have LG P768 Android 4.1.2. I can move apps to SD using [Move2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.androgames.move2sd&hl=en)

some app2sd (that can't work) will show this error "device does not have a real primary external storage or the primary external storage is emulated"

Answer (score 0):

Compared to other devices, there is no "Move to SD card" option in the application manager menu on Galaxy S Duos. I have rooted my phone and I use **folder mount** app to link game data to SD card. I have tried and tested this app, so I can guarantee that this will work on a rooted S Duos. But first, you have to install the game in internal storage. Games like "NFS Most Wanted" are more than 1.8GB, i.e. it exceeds the internal storage. So,in order to play them, you need an app called **external2internal** which swaps internal storage to external. But these apps will not move the whole game. It only moves the game data, but not the APK.

You could find custom ROMs with "Move to SD card" option for this device. But again, the ROMs take away many features while giving some. I recommend NOT to flash any kind of ROMs, and those new users who don't know how complicated rooting a device, I will recommend them to use Kingo Android Root to root their device. But be cautioned, it will void the warranty. In conclusion, S Duos users who are not rooted have no practical solution for this problem and are left helpless.

Answer (score -1):

Follow [this link](http://www.bongizmo.com/blog/moving-all-android-apps-to-sdcard-apps2sd-froyo/) . All the details given in it . If it does not understand your external sd card as memory device you might have to create a new partition in the sd card . Here is a [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/sd-card-partitioning-why-how) for that

Comment: that link is not for the Ice cream sandwich version....,can you please provide a link for the ice cream sandwich version for Samsung galaxy s dueos

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is to create a partition in your SD card and root ur phone. Install an app called [link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en), and link all ur apps to ur SD card.