# Motorola RAZR D3 move application to memory SD

Tags: app2sd, motorola-droid-razr

I'm trying to move the apps that I have installed in the internal memory of the smartphone but I can't because the programs that I'm using say:

> The device does not have a real primary external storage, or the primary external storage is emulated.
>
> Moving app to SD function cannot be supported by this device

I'm using AppMgr II and App2SD and both says some similar.

How can I move the apps?

Comment: The very same issue is described with [What should I do now to move apps to SD in my Samsung Galaxy S Duos (ICS)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35878/16575) You might want to try the solutions offered there -- and please report back if they can be applied to your device as well, and whether they solved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: I reply to the answer, it's seem that (for now) the only solution it's to roor the device and the install some app like "GL to SD"

Answer (score -1):

- Root the device (in this case the razr d3)
- Install the application (a game i.e.) in the memory SD.
- Unroot the device (to have the last update of the S.O., i don't have find how to unroot an razr d3)

I don't have test this solution but maybe in a few weeks i will try it :)

Links:

http://youtu.be/3WZBb4W0-ds how to root D1 and D3 device.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JA8TKNWTEk how to use GL to SD (root)

Well, basicly the problem is that we will avoid the warranty of the mobile.

Comment: Enrique, could you please include an abstract with your answer? If those links die, it would become "useless" otherwise. Thanks a lot!