# How to move system programs to sd card?

Tags: app2sd, htc-explorer

System programs like youtube, gmail and maps are consuming over 50 MB of my HTC Explorer (v2.3) which is a rather low end android phone and has only 128 MB of system memory. 
As a result the low memory notification is kind of consistently visible. Can I (how) safely move them to the sd card?

EDIT: My device is rooted.

Answer (score 1):

As @[Cyborgz](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/28847/cyborgz) said, you have to first root the system. Take a look at [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) question to see your device is listed. Even if not, probably your device's closest like HTC Hero for more information.

Once rooted you have to partition your SD card to create a SD-Ext partition. See the question "[SD card partitioning? Why? How?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/sd-card-partitioning-why-how)" to know how.

Then you can use apps like [Link2SD](http://www.link2sd.info/faq) to move few user applications to SD card and create link of few user applications to the sd-ext partition. By this way you would have created loads of free memory in your device. If you still want to get more like moving YouTube, GMail and Maps, you can use Link2SD to first convert them to user app (from system app) and move or link them (most likely moving will not be permitted).

Comment: my device is already rooted.

Answer (score 0):

In Order to access the System folder Root access is required. All Systems apps are available in `/system/apps` folder, if you have root access, just choose the required app and move it SD Card with the help of file manager.

If you would like to move your system data partition i.e., System/Data you can try [This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1716124)

Hope it helps.

PS: Please do a research before doing any thing in system folder, if you mess up, then i am not responsible!!!

Comment: Not all apps can be moved to SDCard, some are required to be on `/system/apps` partition...

Comment: `/system` partition has no effect on the "low memory" notification. It's rather the updates to system apps (those are *not* stored on `/system` but rather in `/data`) which are the crucial point here. Not sure if those can be moved to SD.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate approach without root device. By using sdk tool to set install location as sd card, you can move most. It is a good middle of the round solution.

See url - http://techgage.com/article/moving_your_non-movable_android_apps_to_an_sd_card/

Comment: Are you sure that works for pre-installed apps? As they are installed in `/system`, they cannot be moved without root access. Maybe their updates could, however.