# How to install the application in SDcard (android phone)?

Tags: applications, sd-card, app2sd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install APK files on SDCARD.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/how-to-install-apk-files-on-sdcard)

I would like to install the .apk file into the SD card. Can I do this? If yes then how could I able to perform this in my HTC hero android phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/how-to-install-apk-files-on-sdcard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can "officially" only be done if you are running android-2.2-froyo and you set the app to install on the sdcard.

If you are not running android-2.2-froyo then the only way to do it is with some "hackery", which involves partitioning your sdcard, symbolic links and some other things. There are some custom ROMs that would have this built in

The non-froyo methods also involve having your phone rooted.

Comment: Officially, the app also needs to support install to SD card.  Widgets and live backgrounds should never be installed to the SD card.