# How to move Applications from phone to SD Card?

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sd-card, app2sd

I have recently purchased Sony Xperia Tipo Dual phone, I couldn't find to move the apps to SD card. We can able to move the Apps from phone standard memory to Phone Internal Memory.

Can any one give me the solution to move the Applications from phone to SD Card?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Have you searched this site? Your question is one of the most FAQ. Try Link2SD or Apps2SD apps from Play Store.

Comment: I see several possible duplicates in the "Related" list in the right sidebar. Here's a couple: [How to install the application in SDcard (android phone)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5191) [Is there any way to move apps to my sd card in android 2.1 on my phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4421)

Comment: I just added the `app2sd` tag to your question. Clicking on that brings up some related problems, which might prove helpful to you. Also, the "Related" section next to your question might have some useful information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install the application in SDcard (android phone)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5191/how-to-install-the-application-in-sdcard-android-phone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install APK files on SDCARD?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/how-to-install-apk-files-on-sdcard)

Answer (score 1):

As the phones internal memory acts as the sdcard (internal SD card), that is what Android moves apps to.

You can use a 3rd party app to move it to the external SD Card, however.