# help in moving apps to external

Tags: app2sd, external-sd

I need to know that is it possible to move your apps from phone storage to external storage SD card

as i have following storages:

1. internal storage of 800 MB
2. phone storage of 2.60 GB
3. External storage of 14 GB

i need to move my huge sized data of games like asphalt, gladiator2 and other huge sized games  from phone storage i.e 2.60 gb to external storage i.e 14 gb
android doesnt show any option to move such apps to external sd as it allows only moving apps to sd card from internal storage
i want to install more games without uninstalling any previous one because when i install anything from playstore it says insuffcient storage because my phone storgae is full.. and external storage is almost half empty. 1 thing more that my phone is rooted.

quick response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The answer depends greatly on the model of your phone and the Android OS version it's running.

Comment: Not to mention the apps themselves. Not all of them allow for moving to the SD card.

Comment: Have you looked at other questions in the [tag:app2sd] tag? There are a lot of similar questions there, including this one: [How to move Applications from phone to SD Card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30448)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings | Apps` and tap the app you'd like to move. If there's a "Move to SD card" button there and it's lit up, you can move the app to the SD card. Tap the button and it'll start the process.

Note:

- Not all apps can be moved the SD card
- Even if you move the app to the SD card, some of it will remain in internal storage
- Apps on the SD card **will not work** when your device is connected to a computer via USB

(This also assumes you're using a device and version of the OS that supports moving apps to the SD card. I'm not talking about custom ROMs that let you use the SD card as if it was internal storage.)

Back when I had a device with an SD card, two of my most critical apps were [SDMove](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beaglebros.SDMove) and [SDWatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beaglebros.SDWatch).

**SDMove** gives you a consolidated list of all the apps that *can* be moved to the SD card and links to the app info page so you can do that. **SDWatch** checks an app when it is installed to alert you if it can be moved to the SD card.