# Can I install applications in memory card in Samsung Galaxy 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-apollo, app2sd, link2sd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install APK files on SDCARD.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/how-to-install-apk-files-on-sdcard)

Hi ,
   I ran out of phone memory installing various applications . Looks like there is no obvious way to install apps into my memory card ?

Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

You need Android 2.2 to install applications to the SD-card.

Comment: My galaxy 3 runs Android 2.1 . Can it be upgraded to 2.2 ?

Comment: @vinoth According to the Galaxy 3's entry in the When Will My Phone Get Froyo question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo Froyo (Android 2.2) should be available for your phone. You can check for and install the update by connecting your phone to a PC that is running Samsung's Kies software, if it doesn't show as available there, then it could be down to your phone company being slow to approve the update.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted you can also use an app like Link2SD after partitioning your SD card to install apps there.

I'm using a rooted Samsung Spica on 2.1 and have done it myself without any issues.

Follow the step-by-step instructions [in this question/answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6438/sd-card-partitioning-why-how).